# SSD messed up - no idea how to fix it on Linux

Tags: grub, ssd, kubuntu, partition-table, rescue

I'm stuck with my netbook (Dell Latitude 3380). Used it for a year: worked fine. I bought and put new SSD, installed Kubuntu 18.04 on it.  For a couple hours it worked very well. Then it froze when I was copying files from external HDD and doing some stuff. Then it worked really slowly so I thought to give 19.04 a try. Now, I guess, is a big mistake: I manually changed partition table. Previously there was one ext4 partition mounted as /, second one as /home and swap. I deleted the first one, created 200MB EFI at the begining, rest formatted again to ext4, /. I left /home and swap without formatting.

System installed with no errors or warnings, but after rebooting there is only grub rescue. I can use it to boot linux from Live USB (this is how I write this) - so the module files are there and can be read. (I can, of course, boot directly from USB by BIOS). GRUB sees partition on this disk. /dev/sda1 (EFI partition) is set as BOOT but system itself and GRUB files are on /dev/sda7. I guess this is a problem.

But any attempt to use gparted, fdisk, wipefs or fsck on my /dev/sda from either Ubuntu Live or System Rescue CD Live ends with weird error. Every two minutes I get messages like:

```
INFO: task fsck.ext2:6081 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
Not tainted 4.19.34-1-lts #1
```

ctrl+c doesn't help. I've to do a hard reset. Kubuntu installer gives me error messages like `"/dev/sda1/" cannot be accessed` so I can't proceed further than time zone setting. My BIOS has an option to wipe internal disk. I run it, but it ends with error and no details. I did

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda
```

and left the computer overnight. Worked without errors, wrote ca 512GB of zeros but nothing really changed ;P Partitions are still there, as I can see them from grub rescue. I was able to run fdisk-l once and saw partition table. Then I tried fsck /dev/sda and it again produced "not tainted" situation.

What's going on in here? Is this a faulty SSD? Seems not, because on my first installation I was able to use it quite normally. SMART also shows no errors.
I don't care, obviously, about any data on the disk. I just want to do whatever to make a clean install of a new Kubuntu (or Mint or whatever).

This is `blkid` output:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="D66B-BF6C" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="b9d3b90b-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="eec4f953-b9ba-4579-95f4-8f9a8d6821a3" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b9d3b90b-05"
/dev/sda7: UUID="8b9d60f7-fa03-459a-9d34-784d4259338a" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b9d3b90b-07"
```

Some additional info: My netbook has been working fine for a year on Kubuntu 16.04, except that once in a long while it hanged up with some I/O error, message contained also a sector number of HDD. (if you think it's relevant, I can provide more detailed desc)

My new SSD is Goodram CX400 512GB.

Whenever I boot USB with Kubuntu 18.04, 19.04, Mint 19.1 or Fedora 30 KDE I see such messages (didn't see them while on Kubuntu 16.04):

```
May 28 06:38:22 kubuntu kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 6: ee2000000040110a
May 28 06:38:22 kubuntu kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fef1ce80 MISC 43880014086 
May 28 06:38:22 kubuntu kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:806e9 TIME 1559025486 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 9a
May 28 06:38:22 kubuntu kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: Machine check events logged
May 28 06:38:22 kubuntu kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 7: ee2000000040110a
May 28 06:38:22 kubuntu kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fef1cec0 MISC 47880014086 
May 28 06:38:22 kubuntu kernel: mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:806e9 TIME 1559025486 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 9a
```

I found people having similar issues on Dell laptops and claiming that these are false positives ([example1](https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/1/4/559), [example2](https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/DELL-Inspiron-5567-MCE-Errors-On-Boot-Linux-Kernel/td-p/5163980)).

Memtest after few passes produces no errors at all.

Comment: Some issue with your hardware itself check BIOS.

Comment: What do you precisely mean? There's a diagnostic tool in my BIOS but I run it and it claims that everything is ok: "all tests passed". As I wrote, memtest and SMART didn't report anything. Any suggestions what else if my hardware and how I should test then?

Comment: Possible reasons for the timeout are explained [here](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/09/22/linux-kernel-panic-issue-fix-hung_task_timeout_secs-blocked-120-seconds-problem/), the issue with `fsck` on a clean boot makes and inaccessibilty to `gparted` it sound hardware related. What is the old SSD model? And if you reinstall it, does the machine function?

Comment: @bu5hman : the old disk was actually a HDD, Toshiba MQ01ACF050. I reinstalled it and everything works just fine. So it's all just a broken new SSD?

Comment: I misunderstood your original post (thought the old was SSD) but I was fishing to see if the issue was SATA/nvme related. My laptop will take an M2 SATA but not nvme was an issue I was looking for with you, but the fact that you installed and ran for a while (drivers must have been there) before failing and then have read/formatting issues suggests hardware to me. If the old disk boots and runs fine then that points to the SSD itself rather than a connector or motherboard issue.

Comment: What happens if you connect the SSD through USB with an appropriate external connector? Does it live?

Comment: The initial good performance and degradation may have been related to [heat dissipation](https://forum-en.msi.com/index.php?topic=275902.0). [Failure](https://photographylife.com/m-2-nvme-drive-overheating-failure) has been known although not in such a short time.

Comment: I don't have any external connector, I'll try to buy one or borrow from somebody and then I'm gonna check if it works this way...

Comment: So when I connect this SSD through the external connector my system recognizes it. I can read&write data. But: in GParted I tried to delete all the partitions. It finishes without errors, but moment later they're there again and after mounting I can access all the folders again. And these are always only old files -those that I had added on previous mount moment ago aren't there anymore.

Comment: Then it sounds very much like the issue above. The system attempts to write, the buffer fills and then is flushed. Not sure why it wouldnt be recognised as an error but is (as it sounds) all write operations fail. Since you can read it the disk has probably set itself as read-only. I have seen this on usb sticks after power surges. Mail the manufacturers technical dept and explain it's gone read only. I did this with a usb and got a replacement..... you never know. Good luck.

Comment: Out of interest, did you fix it?

Comment: In a sense, yes. I wrote to the support and they admitted it's a disk's fault. It was still under warranty so I sent it today to them. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Glad to hear you got a result ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all write operations fail and the data is preserved it very much sounds as if the drive has  set itself as read only, probably as the result of an error condition (over-heating, power surge etc).

Mail the manufacturers tech support and explain the problem. They may help with a fix/reset or possibly replace the drive.

support@goodram.com